# Who is downvoting each and every question?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Four years ago I asked this: [Why there's so many down votes in question list?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/why-theres-so-many-down-votes-in-question-list)

The problem is still there and clearly the "downvote so they understand their question is terrible" guide is not working in this sub.

[image]

Maybe we should try not to kick and push people out of this sub to other platforms like Reddit. Can we not downvote them? If the question isn't well formatted or is not clear or whatever, just leave a comment and ignore the question without downvoting it.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with you. As a moderator it irritates me when many questions quickly get downvoted, rather than an attempt being made to improve the question, or to simply ask for clarifications.

People are allowed to downvote questions, and they don't have to explain themselves, so they are working within the rules.

Egregious multiple downvotes (or upvotes) can be detected and reversed, however modest amounts are hard to fix.

Maybe the downvoters are simply trying to be annoying. The best way to combat that is to just ignore them. Ignore the downvotes unless there are a lot of them. If there are a lot, perhaps consider what could be done to improve the question.

Comment: Someone down-voted both yours and my question, seems like we have troll on this site.

Comment: I stick my tongue out at the trolls! :P