# Pinned post in the Arduino forum?

Tags: feature-request

I've been browsing the Arduino forums for years. I have no idea why I find it so fun, but after all this time, I see the same frikin problem over and over with posts!

People never include schematics/drawings! 90% of the questions the OP asks why his code isn't working, and the first 4 comments are "Please post schematics". Most new people don't understand how it's usually quite helpful to have the entire scope of the project laid out for those trying to help.

Wouldn't it be nice to have a pinned post at the top of the forum that outlines how to ask a question? It might save these new users as well as the helpers a little frustration. Or, when creating your first post as so many folks are, there's a template that you are presented with to overview before creating your first post.

Just my thoughts.

Comment: The Arduino forum? Or here?

Comment: The Arduino Stack Exchange...

Comment: There is no such thing as a pinned post on stack exchange. It's not a forum in the traditional sense but a question and answer site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a forum, but assuming you are referring to Arduino Stack Exchange, I have a post [How to ask a good question for Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange). That mentions, amongst other things, posting your code and a schematic (and your error messages!).

I did a similar thing for the Arduino Forum [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/read-this-before-posting-a-programming-question/95349).

What can I say? People don't read these posts, or if they do they ignore them.

I'll tell you what the problem is. You [1] are in a hurry to get a problem solved. You want an answer and you want it **now**. You don't have time to read boring lectures about  how to make a good post, you don't have time to post a schematic, or your code, or to tell us what parts you are using. You don't even have time to report what the error messages are, or what the problem actually is.

You just want **answers** and you hope that with minimal effort you will get them.

I don't want to sound negative, but, hey, if you are planning to ask a question here *don't be that person*.

---

[1] Not you personally, AJ_Smoothie.